# Word occurrence method not counting

Tags: java

I have a method that should count the occurrence of a word in a sentence and return the results. For some reason it's not counting. The code always returns `0`.

Here's the code.

```
public static int countOccurance (String word, String sentence) {
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != sentence.length()-word.length()-2; i++) {
    if (sentence.substring(i, i+word.length()-1).equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my method?

Comment: What is it doing then?

Comment: sample input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took your code and deleted your -1 and -2, since I didn't understand why they were there.

```
public static int countOccurance (String word, String sentence) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != sentence.length()-word.length(); i++) {
        if (sentence.substring(i, i+word.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Tried this.

```
String sentence = "yakkity yak yak yak attack";
String word = "yak";

int wc = countOccurance (word, sentence);

System.out.println("The string \""+sentence+"\" contains the word "+word+" "+wc+" times.");
```

Result:

```
The string "yakkity yak yak yak attack" contains the word yak 4 times.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sub-string is off, and your loop position check is incorrect too. When I change your method to,

```
public static int countOccurance(String word, String sentence) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i + word.length() < sentence.length(); i++) {
        if (sentence.substring(i, i + word.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(
                word)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countOccurance("Hello", "hello hello world"));
    System.out.println(countOccurance("Fi", "Fee Fi Fum"));
}
```

it outputs the expected

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to check for the " " space,,, as each space to be encounter... count++ .....
and you can also check for the '\n' in the check case
And make the loop to end at  \0 string null character!!

Comment: look at \0 char? isn't that a c staff?

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex

```
    Matcher m= Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b").matcher(sentence);
    while(m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Collections.frequency()` method on a `List` of words sidesteps the whole need for keeping track of the counter yourself:

```
 public static int countOccurance (String word, String sentence) {
     List<String> words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "));
     return Collections.frequency(words,word);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because others have already covered why your current code does not work, I would like to use this answer to make a recommendation. I would personally recommend using Java's regex API for this problem. Using something like the following;

```
public static int countOccurances(String regex, String sentence) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
    int count = 0;
    while(m.find()) count++;
    
    return count;
}
```

I hope this helps.

- [Official Java Regex Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String sentence = "Hello truc, Hello machi, and Hello all !";
    final String word = "hello";

    System.out.println(count(sentence.toLowerCase(), word.toLowerCase()));
}

public static int count(String sentence, String word){
    int cpt = 0;
    while(sentence.contains(word)){
        cpt++;
        sentence = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(word) + word.length());
    }
    return cpt;
}
```

Comment: Uhm.. this code has a lot of overhead for a very symple task.